# Neo4j browser page is empty

Tags: ubuntu, browser, neo4j

I've installed Neo4j DB to Ubuntu 16.04 by this manual - http://www.exegetic.biz/blog/2016/09/installing-neo4j-ubuntu-16-04/
but http://localhost:7474/browser/ always returns empty page. Source code page is:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=en>

<head>
<meta charset=UTF-8>
<title>Neo4j Browser</title>
<style>
    * {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0
    }
    body,
    html {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%
    }
</style>
<link rel=apple-touch-icon sizes=57x57 href=assets/images/device-icons/apple-touch-icon-57x57.png>
<link rel=apple-touch-icon sizes=60x60 href=assets/images/device-icons/apple-touch-icon-60x60.png>
<link rel=apple-touch-icon sizes=72x72 href=assets/images/device-icons/apple-touch-icon-72x72.png>
<link rel=apple-touch-icon sizes=76x76 href=assets/images/device-icons/apple-touch-icon-76x76.png>
<link rel=apple-touch-icon sizes=114x114 href=assets/images/device-icons/apple-touch-icon-114x114.png>
<link rel=apple-touch-icon sizes=120x120 href=assets/images/device-icons/apple-touch-icon-120x120.png>
<link rel=apple-touch-icon sizes=144x144 href=assets/images/device-icons/apple-touch-icon-144x144.png>
<link rel=apple-touch-icon sizes=152x152 href=assets/images/device-icons/apple-touch-icon-152x152.png>
<link rel=apple-touch-icon sizes=180x180 href=assets/images/device-icons/apple-touch-icon-180x180.png>
<link rel=icon type=image/png href=assets/images/device-icons/favicon-32x32.png sizes=32x32>
<link rel=icon type=image/png href=assets/images/device-icons/android-chrome-192x192.png sizes=192x192>
<link rel=icon type=image/png href=assets/images/device-icons/favicon-96x96.png sizes=96x96>
<link rel=icon type=image/png href=assets/images/device-icons/favicon-16x16.png sizes=16x16>
<link rel=manifest href=assets/images/device-icons/manifest.json>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href=assets/images/device-icons/favicon.ico>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://gc.kis.v2.scr.kaspersky-labs.com/FF2CECD2-CC13-EA49-81AB-5360136C63AA/main.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
<script src=assets/js/neoPlanner.js></script>
<script src=assets/js/d3.min.js></script>
<script src=assets/js/canvg/rgbcolor.js></script>
<script src=assets/js/canvg/StackBlur.js></script>
<script src=assets/js/canvg/canvg.js></script>
</head>

<body>
<div id=mount></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="vendor-89ea00473a9f602cff10.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app-89ea00473a9f602cff10.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

neo4j.log is empty now because i deleted it (for watching new logs). New file wasn't created.
What's wrong?

Comment: It is best to use .tar version for linux, which you just unzip and it works... download here https://neo4j.com/download/other-releases/... also are you running your server on the same computer as you are opening browser ?

Comment: Thanks! It works now. Cause of problem was nginx proxy. I've opened 7474 and 7687 ports and turn off nginx proxy for it.